# If else in spring context with the prop key

Tags: spring

Is there a way to provide another value for key if null? I want to use the source and dest db. But if dest db details are null then use source.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" />
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${maximumPoolSize}" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="${idleTimeout}" />
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="${connectionTimeout}" />

    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="url">${dest.db.url}</prop>
            <prop key="user">${dest.db.user}</prop>
            <prop key="password">${dest.db.password}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

What I tried:

```
    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="url">${dest.db.url?:${src.db.url}}</prop>
            <prop key="user">${dest.db.user?:${src.db.user}}</prop>
            <prop key="password">${dest.db.password?:${src.db.password}}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Though the dest db details are not null, the data is being written into the source. Not sure why? Is there something wrong  in the way I'm defining it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator to specify an if-else condition in spel. Take a look at this:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-el-ternary-operator-if-then-else-example/

Comment: Setting a prop name value that way is ok, for the if else, but I'm looking to set a prop key value which is not the same way. In a name value you can '#{value}' to specify but in a key value, its direct <key>Value</key>